# How to select all checkbox when i checked all check boxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I want to select all checkbox checked when i select all checkboxes in my dropdown menu. I am a beginner js developer need help. This is my js code

```
var expanded = false;
function showCheckboxes() {
var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
if (!expanded) {
checkboxes.style.display = "block";
expanded = true;
} else {
checkboxes.style.display = "none";
expanded = false;
}
}
var selectallBox = document.getElementById('selectall');
var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.select-me');
selectallBox.addEventListener('click', function() {

for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkBoxes[i] != selectallBox)
        checkBoxes[i].checked = selectallBox.checked;
}


})
for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
   checkBoxes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    selectallBox.checked = false; 
})
}
document.querySelector('.close-check-box').addEventListener('click' , function(){
checkboxes.style.display = 'none'
})
```

This is my js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b9ueL3fw/

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question, It seems to be working already ?

Comment: No it is not working

Comment: Your html? Post it

Comment: my html is in js fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the total check box with the checked check box count, if both length are same then  set check box `checked` property to `true`, otherwise set to `false`:

```
var selectedCount = document.querySelectorAll('.select-me:checked').length;
if(checkBoxes.length == selectedCount){
  selectallBox.checked = true;
}
else{
  selectallBox.checked = false; 
}
```

```js
var expanded = false;
var selectBox = document.querySelector('.selectBox')
selectBox.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
});


var selectallBox = document.getElementById('selectall');
var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.select-me');
selectallBox.addEventListener('click', function() { 
  for (let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkBoxes[i] != selectallBox)
      checkBoxes[i].checked = selectallBox.checked;
  }
})

for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
   checkBoxes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
   var selectedCount = document.querySelectorAll('.select-me:checked').length;
  if(checkBoxes.length == selectedCount){
    selectallBox.checked = true;
  }
  else{
      selectallBox.checked = false; 
    }
  });
}
document.querySelector('.close-check-box').addEventListener('click' , function(){
 checkboxes.style.display = 'none'
})
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 400px;
}
.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}
.selectBox select {
  width: 100%; 
}
.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px rgb(169, 169, 169) solid;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
label {
 display: block;
}
select {
 padding: 6px 12px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.close-check-box:link,
.close-check-box:visited {
 padding: 1px 25px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 300;
 background-color: #3498db;
 border: 1px solid #3498db;
 color: #fff;
 margin-left: 14px;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}

hr.style-two {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(169, 169, 169, 0), rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.75), rgba(169, 169, 169, 0));
}
```

```html
<form method="GET">
  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox">
      <select> 
        <option>Select an option</option>
      </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <label for="selectall">
        <input type="checkbox"  id="selectall" / class="mr-3 ml-3">Select All</label>
        <hr class="style-two">
      <label for="one">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="1" id="one" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">First</label>
      <label for="two">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="2" id="two" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">Second</label>
         <label for="three">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="3" id="three" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">First</label>
      <label for="four">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" value="4" id="four" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">Second</label>
       <label for="five">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" value="5" id="five" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">First</label>
      <label for="six">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" value="6" id="six" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">Second</label>
       <label for="seven">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox7" value="7" id="seven" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">First</label>
      <label for="eight">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox8" value="8" id="eight" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">Second</label>
       <label for="nine">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox9" value="9" id="nine" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">First</label>
      <label for="ten">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox10" value="10" id="ten" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">Second</label>
   
       <a class="close-check-box" href="#">click</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var expanded = false;
var selectBox = document.querySelector(".selectBox");
selectBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
});
let checkboxesCheckedCount = 0;

var selectallBox = document.getElementById("selectall");
var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".select-me");
selectallBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkBoxes[i] != selectallBox)
      checkBoxes[i].checked = selectallBox.checked;
    checkboxesCheckedCount = selectallBox.checked ? checkBoxes.length : 0;
  }
});

for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
  checkBoxes[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    selectallBox.checked = false;
    checkboxesCheckedCount = this.checked ? checkboxesCheckedCount +1 : checkboxesCheckedCount -1

    if (checkboxesCheckedCount === checkBoxes.length) {
      selectallBox.checked = true;
    }
  });
}
document
  .querySelector(".close-check-box")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
  });
```

```css
.multiselect{width:400px}.selectBox{position:relative}.selectBox select{width:100%}.overSelect{position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0}#checkboxes{display:none;border:1px #a9a9a9 solid;padding-top:10px;border-radius:5px;margin-top:10px;height:200px;overflow-y:scroll}label{display:block}select{padding:6px 12px;border-radius:5px}.close-check-box:link,.close-check-box:visited{padding:1px 25px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:300;background-color:#3498db;border:1px solid #3498db;color:#fff;margin-left:14px;box-shadow:0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:20px;display:inline-block}hr.style-two{border:0;height:1px;background-image:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(169,169,169,0),rgba(169,169,169,.75),rgba(169,169,169,0))}
```

```html
<form method="GET"><div class="multiselect"><div class="selectBox"> <select><option>Select an option</option></select><div class="overSelect"></div></div><div id="checkboxes"><label for="selectall"> <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" / class="mr-3 ml-3">Select All</label><hr class="style-two"> <label for="one"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="1" id="one" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">First</label> <label for="two"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="2" id="two" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">Second</label> <label for="three"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="3" id="three" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">First</label> <label for="four"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" value="4" id="four" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">Second</label> <label for="five"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" value="5" id="five" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">First</label> <label for="six"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" value="6" id="six" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">Second</label> <label for="seven"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox7" value="7" id="seven" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">First</label> <label for="eight"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox8" value="8" id="eight" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">Second</label> <label for="nine"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox9" value="9" id="nine" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">First</label> <label for="ten"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox10" value="10" id="ten" / class="mr-3 ml-3 select-me">Second</label><a class="close-check-box" href="#">click</a></div></div> <button type="submit">submit</button></form>
```